# No action triggered after placing an order

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, configuration

I am making my custom payment method module for Magento 1.9.1.1 and I want to do some action when user proceeds to checkout, before the order is placed, and after the order is placed. I implemented action for `proceed to checkout` event, and then I wanted to add an observer for event when order is placed. In my `config.xml` file I have this:

```
<events>
  <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index>
    <observers>
      <mycheckout>
        <class>Custom_Paymentmethod_Model_Observer</class>
        <method>checkoutStarted</method>
        <type>singleton</type>
      </mycheckout>
    </observers>
   </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index>
   <sales_order_save_after>
     <observers>
       <mycheckout>
         <class>Custom_Paymentmethod_Model_Observer</class>
         <method>initiateCheckout</method>
         <type>singleton</type>
       </mycheckout>
      </observers>
    </sales_order_save_after>
</events>
```

And in my Observer.php file I got:

```
class Custom_Paymentmethod_Model_Observer
{
    public function checkoutStarted(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        //This action works fine
    }

    public function initiateCheckout(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        //Nothing from here is triggered
    }
}
```

What am I missing here, and what is the issue?

And what event should I use before the order is placed?

Comment: What's exactly your problem? I mean, which event is not firing? None of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are wrongly using the event. I don't think there is an event called `sales_order_save_after`.

Use this event instead: `sales_order_place_after` and also change the observer name `mycheckout` to something else, anything, just need to be unique than what you have used earlier.

**Each observer should be wrapped with a unique identifier.**

So your code becomes this in `config.xml`:

```
<sales_order_place_after>
 <observers>
   <mycheckout_place_after>
     <class>Custom_Paymentmethod_Model_Observer</class>
     <method>initiateCheckout</method>
     <type>singleton</type>
   </mycheckout_place_after>
  </observers>
</sales_order_place_after>
```

Full list of events in magento [here](https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-9/).

**[UPDATE]**

> And what event should I use before the order is placed?

Events for order:

```
sales_order_place_after => this will fire after order is placed
sales_order_place_before => this will fire before order is placed
etc...
```

In fact, you could tell when they will be fired from their naming. This is good stuff from Magento team.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that stuff, that's pretty useful to know! I changed like you proposed, but still not working. Now in my config file I have: 

    `<sales_order_place_before>
  <observers>
     <mycheckout_before_place>
            <class> Custom_Paymentmethod_Model_Observer      </class>
  <method>initiateCheckout</method>
             <type>singleton</type>
           </mycheckout_before_place>
        </observers>
     </sales_order_place_before>`

And in my php file I put just redirection to google, to see if it will work, and still nothing..

Comment: You can simply add this in your `initiateCheckout` function: `Mage::log('fired', null, 'worked.log');` and then try with placing order, then check if there is file called `worked.log` in your `var/log/` folder.

Comment: Fired! Checked my log file, everything worked ok, looks like for some reason redirection couldn't occur at that point, but now  everything is ok. Thanks a lot!